# tslearn TimeSeriesKMeans output

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, k-means

Can someone explain what the visualizations are showing in the [tslearn - kmeans clustering](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_kmeans.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-plot-kmeans-py) example? I've implemented the method without any tweaking and my results are much less obvious, although I haven't tweaked any parameters. What am I looking at in the example plots and my own?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this plot, each subplot presents a cluster (you are doing k-means with k=3, hence you generate 3 clusters):

- in gray, time series assigned to the given cluster are represented
- in red, the centroid (computed using [DBA algorithm](http://lig-membres.imag.fr/bisson/cours/M2INFO-AIW-ML/papers/PetitJean11.pdf)) is superimposed.

As shown in tslearn docs, you could also use soft-dtw that has a gamma parameter to control barycenter smoothing